# After Purging wso2 table recommended, I lost my analytics and statistics in publisher->analytic menu

Tags: database, wso2, store, wso2-api-manager

my memory of database server is increasing so fast, specially databases: analytics_event_store and analytics_processed_data_store. So I decided to purge data that it's not important. after purging I understand every data was needed for analytics in publisher->analytic menu has been removed and no statistic I have in analytics menu.

I purge these tables according to [https://medium.com/@dinushad92/how-to-purge-data-in-apim-analytics-1d3b53b570d0] and [just purging data part](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM191/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics+Using+WSO2+DAS#PublishingAPIRuntimeStatisticsUsingWSO2DAS-PurgingData(optional)). even in these sites written "Make sure you do not purge data in tables other than those mentioned above as that will delete your summarized historical data." and I just write mentioned tables, I lost my summerized data and no more API statistics shown in publisher->analytics menu.
But I need these statistics.

Is there any way that I can remove not important data and make free space for my incoming data on wso2 database that keep my data needed for API statistics??

Comment: do you have a distributed (clustered) setup or it's a single server ? If you have clustered nodes, then you can check your missing data from other node's data. There is one way you can check is get the copy of `/solr` from `<APIM_HOME>` directory & find the data. [This](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Purging+Analytics+Data) is how you should purge the data.

Comment: no I don't have a clustered server, I have single one. And my missing data is for 3 days because of configure form that it's ok, but my main problem is about increasing my used memory that I need to make it free.

Comment: Have you tried with steps given in the link I've posted ?